# Obtain multiple object data from LINQ

Tags: linq, concatenation

Little bit stuck strugling with WP7 LINQ sorting. I have a list (Metro) which i sort with LINQ such that i obtain the order according to Line ( which is part of the Metro list objects). But I want more information about my objects from my list than just the Line info. Is it possible to obtain straight into the LINQ to gain addition information that each object in the list Metro has other than just line but still sort it the same way?

```
var stationByLine = from metro in source
                    group metro by metro.Line into c
                    orderby c.Key
                    select new Group<Metro>(C.key, C);

this.citiesListGropus.ItemsSource = stationByLine;
```

I read that maybe using Concat i should be able to solve this but not really sure how to do that....

Thanks Krst

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear why you're *grouping* at all. Why not just use `OrderBy`?

```
var stationByLine = source.OrderBy(metro => metro.Line);
```

Comment: It is for the WP7 Toolkit (longlistselector) and as I see it I need to group the items as the group class (public class Group<T> : IEnumerable<T>) I use needs to implement IEnumerable.

Comment: @Krst: It's not really clear what you mean - but the result of `OrderBy` is `IEnumerable<T>`.